# heroku push Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

my problem is `Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at 127.0.0.1:27017`, when i'm pushing on heroku.

I'm using mongomapper.

config:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
  options:
    w: 1
    pool_size: 1
    slave_ok: false
    ssl: false

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: devname

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: testname
  w: 0

production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: devname
```

connection:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)

MongoMapper.database = "appname-#{Rails.env}"
```

Comment: please show heroku vars, and make sure that mongo is run on 27017 port for heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fixed it by changed connection config to
if ENV["MONGOLAB_URL"]
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["MONGOLAB_URL"])
  MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.from_uri(ENV["MONGOLAB_URL"])
  MongoMapper.database = uri.path.gsub(/^\//, '')
else
  MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost')
  MongoMapper.database = "dbname"
end

and inside mongo.yml file
production:
 uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI']%>
```